# Four Activities don't display Toast

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have four activities:

Activity A

```
 private void addCard() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetNumberActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CREATE);
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CREATE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data.hasExtra("data")) {
                // Card has been create
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Karata została wygenerowana.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Activity B

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(GetNumberActivity.this, ScanQrCodeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, uunitValue);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then in the second activity I have to pass data to the third activity.

Activity C

```
    Card card = new Card(path3, base32, nameCard, intervalTotp, passwordHotp, getDate(), expirationDate, hotpValue);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ScanQrCodeActivity.this, Stage3Activity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("card", card);
                                    startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Activity D

```
Intent data = new Intent(Stage3Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
                data.putExtra("data", card);
                startActivityForResult(data, RESULT_OK);
```

When I press the button on Activity A, the Toast is not shown.

Comment: Did you `setResult()` anywhere?

Comment: Read about getting result from activity https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Comment: Try to use `Intent data = new Intent(); data.putExtra("data", card); setResult(RESULT_OK, data); finish();` instead of your code in Activity D

Comment: I add this line code but now I click "NEXT"  go to Actitivty B

Comment: Yes, because activity B wasn't finished

Answer (score 4):

You need to update your code as follow

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CREATE) {
            if (data.hasExtra("data")) {
                // Card has been create
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Karata została wygenerowana.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

First check for `RESULT_OK` and then proceed further

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `getApplication()` with `this` (the context of the current activity)

```
Toast.makeText(this.class, "Karata została wygenerowana.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Toast  should display when go to click on Actitvty four

Answer (score 0):

Use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `getApplication()` in your `makeText()` method